# How do I access a Docker container running in a Hyper-V VM from an external machine?

Tags: docker, hyper-v

For $REASONS, I am trying to spin up a Docker image in a Hyper-V VM that is part of a failover cluster. In pictures, that looks like this (each component will be labeled with a name that I will hereafter use to describe that component):

```
------------------------------------------
| Physical failover cluster              |
| (hypervisor)                           |
|  ------------------------------------  |
|  | Hyper-V VM with Docker installed |  |
|  | (docker-host)                    |  |
|  |  --------------------            |  |
|  |  | Docker container |            |  |
|  |  | (container)      |            |  |
|  |  |                  |            |  |
|  |  --------------------            |  |
|  |                                  |  |
|  ------------------------------------  |
|                                        |
------------------------------------------
```

(Yes, I know this is a dumb idea; no, that is not the question. The question is whether I can make the dumb idea show some semblance of working like I want it to.)

I've got `docker-container` running properly on `docker-host`, and if I fire up a web browser on `docker-host`, I can access the server running in `docker-container`. However, I cannot access the Docker server from any other machine.

I have tried the following:

- Passing all of these `-p` argument strings to Docker (n.b. this app is running over HTTP at the moment, so port 443 shouldn't matter):

  - `-p 80:80`
  - `-p 80:80 -p 443:443`
  - `-p 0.0.0.0:80:80`
  - `-p 127.0.0.1:80:80`
- Adding a network adapter to the Hyper-V image that was spun up on `docker-host`.
- Reading every StackOverflow post (and other sites as well) that seems to relate to this issue.

If necessary, I may be able to move the Docker container run on `hypervisor` instead of `docker-host`. However, I'd like to know if I can salvage what I've got so far.

Comment: `However, I cannot access the Docker server from any other machine.` Do you have this problem with only docker? For example, if you run a web server on `docker-host`, can you access that web server externally? If not, you may have a firewall related problem. Can you also provide the operating system of `docker-host`?

Comment: I was able to access an IIS-hosted server on `docker-host` (although I was getting a 403, but I'm sure that's an unrelated user error). The OS is Windows Server 2019 Datacenter.

Comment: What's the specific product you're using to run these Docker containers? e.g is it Docker Desktop for Windows, WSL2, or something else?

Comment: Docker Desktop for Windows

Comment: Is any of the firewall advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192267/docker-windows-exposed-ports-cannot-be-accessed-from-outside-the-host) helpful?

Comment: @NickODell yep! I've got it now with the help of firewall configuration and nginx-proxy-manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working now. It turns out you have to open Windows Firewall settings and allow C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.backend.exe through the firewall. After that, plus a little nginx-proxy-manager magic to handle URL proxying properly, it all works great!

Thanks to @NickODell for pointing out the firewall as a culprit!